# How to check for value while creating JSON output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am creating JSON output and want to check the value before I create the key value pair. Is there a way to do it while creating the JSON rather than adding it later?

I am creating this JSON output:

```
sample_json = {
  abc: "abc",
  xyz: "xyz",
  pqr: some_value unless some_value.blank?
}
```

In this example I cannot check for `unless some_value.blank?` while creating the JSON string, so I first create the JSON and then add `pqr: some_value` separately after checking for a blank value, something like this:

```
sample_json = {
  abc: "abc",
  xyz: "xyz"
}

sample_json[:pqr] = some_value unless some_value.blank?
```

Is there is a way to add the check while creating the JSON itself like in the first example?

Comment: Show us your attempt at doing this. Without evidence of your effort it looks like you gave up quickly and want us to write it for you. Read "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)"

Comment: No, there is no way to get inside the JSON serializing process. I'd generate the initial JSON, calculate whatever it is you want, then add that value to the original object and reserialize it. But it sounds like your question is an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)" where you're asking about Y when you should have asked about X. What is the overall goal? What you're trying to do with the JSON is easy but your description isn't good. See "[mcve]" and the linked page. BTW, your example JSON won't create valid JSON output.

Comment: Do all values need to be validated, or just one (or few) of them? How do you assign all other values? Show more of your real code so we can better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

But, some other ways to deal with it, assuming you have active_support, you could use a hash [compact](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/compact) (`sample_json.compact`), which will remove key-value pairs with `nil` values.

But If you do need `!v.blank?`, you could do:

`sample_json.select { |_, value| !value.blank? }`

Answer (score -1):

I'd go about it like this:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'
require 'json'

some_value = 'foo'
hash = {
  abc: "abc",
  xyz: "xyz"
}

hash.merge!(pqr: some_value) unless some_value.blank?
puts hash.to_json 

# >> {"abc":"abc","xyz":"xyz","pqr":"foo"}
```

If `some_value = ''` it'll result in:

```
# >> {"abc":"abc","xyz":"xyz"}
```

Don't create the JSON then try to change it. Instead create the base object, make the test then merge in the change, then serialize to JSON.